# why I can't install socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

there always an error on the console , what's going on?

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\full-stack\proshop-2\socket\node_modules\utf-8-validate
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.15.4 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.2 found at "C:\Users\87302\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or
newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studionpm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\87302\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\87302\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\87302\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\87302\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\87302\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\87302\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\87302\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\87302\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\full-stack\proshop-2\socket\node_modules\utf-8-validate
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\87302\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-06-24T14_21_49_906Z-debug.log

Comment: Install Visual Studio 2017 & Build Tools.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use 'yarn';
first, yarn install
second, yarn
third, yarn run dev

Comment: Thank you! I work for me !! But I still can't install socket.io using npm......

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the Visual Studio and Python on your system, or at least Node isn't aware of them.  You might want to try installing:

- https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools
- https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation

With the Windows Build Tools, you need to run from an elevated (admin) terminal

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
npm install -g node-gyp
```